# How to synchronize an instance passed to multiple places?

Tags: java, multithreading, synchronization

I am working on a code which takes a Map in its constructor, and assigns it to a instance variable. Any method using this instance variable `map` is synchronized.

```
class Foo {

   Map<Int, Int> map;

   Foo ( Map<Int, Int> map ) {
       this.map = map;
   }

   synchornized void put(int x, int y) {
       map.put(x, y);
   }

}
```

But - The client created multiple instances of Foo, and passed same map instance to each of them.

```
Map<Int, Int> map = new HashMap<Int, Int>();
new Foo(map);
new Foo(map);
```

How does `map` get synchronized when used on different instances ? 
Making question broader, how to synchronize an instance sort of globally ?

Answer (score 1):

You should synchronize on the `map`, not the `foo` instance itself.

i.e.

```
void put(int x, int y) {
    synchronized (map) {
       map.put(x, y);
    }
}
```

---

Edit:

The key point here is, you need to understand the concept of synchronization, and to identify the "resource" that is shared and need to be synchronized.  In your case, the shared resource is the Map, not the Foo instance itself.  It is the Map being access concurrently which can cause problem, therefore what you should synchronize on is the shared resource - the Map itself.

There are some other answer suggesting usage of ConcurrentHashMap.  ConcurrentHashMap can help in some situation but it is not going to cover the possibilities of synchronized block (or using some other kind of locking machanism)

ConcurrentMap solve the problem of providing some "complex" operations to Map that in the past need multiple access, and hence need explicit locking on Map.  ConcurrentHashMap goes one step further by making thread safe no-lock read etc.

However, it does not necessary solve the problem.

Assuming what I need to perform on Map is not the provided operations:
e.g.

```
synchronized(map) {
    if (map.contains("key1")) {
        map.put("key3", val1);
    } else if (map.contains("key2")) {
        map.put("key3", val);
    }
 }
```

, then I will need explicit locking (in such case, ConcurrentHashMap may be even worse because it does not allow me to perform explicit synchronization)

Comment: Yes, except that the OP was not asking about a complex operation.

Comment: OP did not tell us what he actually is doing (that piece of code is obviously not real).  What I am trying to tell is the correct concept that he should understand in order to perform synchronization properly.  Maybe it may turn out he just need a thread-safe map (a synchronized map, or a concurrent hash map), but that should be the decision he made with proper understanding instead of blindly take concurrent hash map as a solution for which can be dangerous

Comment: I agree. Synchronize on the map rather than on your own instance. This will pose other problems, though, and you cannot be sure that someone else does not manipulate the map outside of the lock. 

Basically - sharing transient data that needs synchronization is inherently unsafe.

Answer (score 1):

I would like to add to the previous answers.

The problem with the pattern you are describing, without further context, is that you don't know what is actually sent in or what it is used for outside your class. The only thing you know is that it implements Map.

If you need to guard (synchronize) input to this map, then the pattern is broken, because the caller, the one who submitted the map to you in the first place, might have submitted it to other classes as well, or might be manipulating it in other ways, without locks.

The only way you can be sure that the map you are manipulating is properly guarded is if you yourself own it and make sure you don't leak a reference to it to someone else.

This means you should *copy* the submitted map into a private map when you first get it. That way, no one can manipulate it without you knowing.

```
class Foo {
  private final Map<Integer, Integer> map;

  Foo(Map<Integer, Integer> map) {
    this.map = new HashMap<Integer, Integer>(map);
  }
}
```

Then, you can also take advantage of the modern locking style in java:

```
class Foo {
  private final Map<Integer, Integer> map;
  private final ReentrantReadWriteLock mapLock = new ReentrantReadWriteLock();

  Foo(Map<Integer, Integer> map) {
    this.map = new HashMap<Integer, Integer>(map);
  }

  public Integer put(Integer k, Integer v) {
    try {
      mapLock.writeLock().lock();
      return map.put(k, v);
    } finally {
      mapLock.writeLock().unlock();
    }
  }

  public Integer get(Integer k) {
    try {
      mapLock.readLock().lock();
      return map.get(k);
    } finally {
      mapLock.readLock().unlock();
    }
  }
}
```

Be safe - copy your input and don't leak your references!

Answer (score 0):

You could use a ConcurrentHashMap - this type of Map is thread-safe.

Or, synchronize on the class so that any instance of the class will share the same lock.

Or, synchronize on the map.

Comment: 1. Using ConcurrentHashMap does not necessary solve the problem: ConcurrentMap is useful only when the "complex operation" is part of the API of ConcurrentMap.  If the developer need to do several operations to the Map and want it to be atomic, and such operation is not provided by ConcurrentMap, then it is not going to help.  Data will still become inconsistent even you use ConcurrentHashMap.  2. It is irrational to synchronize on the class because conceptually the MAP is the resources to work on and hence to acquire lock on.

Comment: If the problem were more complex and used multiple map operations within a given 'transaction', then you are right. But given the question asked, the three options are valid.

Comment: The question is in fact "Making question broader, how to synchronize an instance sort of globally ?"

Comment: You can't control what map the user of this class is going to submit. In this case you would have to façade it - that would be more than a little cumbersome.

Answer (score 0):

Use [`ConcurrentHashMap`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ConcurrentHashMap.html) instead of `HashMap`.

> A hash table supporting full concurrency of retrievals and adjustable
>   expected concurrency for updates. This class obeys the same functional
>   specification as Hashtable, and includes versions of methods
>   corresponding to each method of Hashtable. However, even though all
>   operations are thread-safe, retrieval operations do not entail
>   locking, and there is not any support for locking the entire table in
>   a way that prevents all access. This class is fully interoperable with
>   Hashtable in programs that rely on its thread safety but not on its
>   synchronization details.

Comment: 1. because concurrent hash map does not necessary be able to replace a synchronized scope. 2. OP is in fact asking for a more general synchronization strategy

Comment: You can't control what map the user of this class is going to submit. In this case you would have to façade it - that would be more than a little cumbersome.